# Merging/Dissolving multiple layers in QGIS Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve, geopackage, virtual-layer

I have several polygon layers that I would like to merge and dissolve within a virtual layer in QGIS. So that any changes made to the individual layers will automatically update in the merged/dissolved Virtual Layer. I want to dissolve the entire layers, not based on any fields.

I’ve used `ST_Union` to do this with a single layer, as below:

```sql
SELECT ST_Union(geometry)
FROM "Important Wetlands"
```

What is the correct syntax to add multiple layers to this Virtual Layer?

The layers are in a GeoPackage.

Comment: Also related : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409644/selecting-all-features-from-two-polygon-layers-in-one-virtual-layer-in-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing it:

1. fetch all geometries then union them

```sql
SELECT st_union(sub.geometry) 
FROM (
   SELECT geometry FROM layerA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT geometry FROM layerB
)sub
```

2. Union each layer independently then union again

```sql
SELECT st_union(sub.geom) 
FROM (
   SELECT st_union(geometry) as geom FROM layerA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT st_union(geometry) as geom FROM layerB
)sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use the `st_union()` function for several times

```sql
SELECT
    st_union(st_union(g1.geometry, g2.geometry))
FROM
    "grid_test" AS g1,
    "grid_test2" AS g2
```

*Input:*

[image: input]

*Output:*

[image: output]